# Check SeLinux Status

Tags: bash, centos7

Using the following code I would like to check the status of SeLinux e.g. enforcing, permissive, disabled. If the status is other then *disabled*, then I will advise the user to disable Selinux.

I'm running the following in a .sh file. The current status of SeLinux is Permissive. Running the following code ends up in the else clause.

```
#! /bin/bash

SELINUXSTATUS=getenforce;

if [ "$SELINUXSTATUS" == "Permissive" ]; then
    echo "Disable SeLinux";
else
    echo "All Good. Continue...";
fi;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
SELINUXSTATUS=$(getenforce)
```

Currently, your script will just set `SELINUXSTATUS` to the literal string `getenforce`. `$(command)` is the magic in `bash` which runs a command and captures its output.

Comment: WOW This works thanks man. I will mark this as an answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `SELINUXSTATUS=$(getenforce)`.
Now your variable SELINUXSTATUS is just string "getenforce".

Answer (score 2):

As @Jon says:

```
    SELINUXSTATUS=$(getenforce)
```

runs the `getenforce` commandf, captures its output and sets the variable to that value.  Alternately,

```
    SELINUXSTATUS=`getenforce`
```

does the same thing.  (Note that those are back-ticks ... not regular single quotes.)

But be aware that there are three possible results from `getenforce`; i.e. `Disabled`, `Permissive` and `Enforcing`.